# How to add multiple implementations to java class using cglib?

Tags: java, cglib

is it possible to support this solution using cglib?

```
interface I { 
void foo(); 
void boo(); 
}

abstract class B implements I { 
  foo();
}

abstract class C implements I { 
  boo();
}

abstract class D extends B {

}
```

The code

```
D d = new D();
d.foo();
d.boo();
```

Comment: @-1 , how can i improve the question?

Comment: they downvote, because they don't understand. When you have OCJP you become Java Expert. They are Java Experts that don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is no problem for CgLib. I have even tried to do it and it was a no problem for me. I use cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar.

If you want to d.boo(); to do nothing I see no problem here.

If you would like to implement something like Java8 default methods there is a little more tricky with passing a state of an object.

The only different is that you need to create an object by Enhancer. If you want to change how "new D();" behaves you should try AspectJ. I think its possible to make it work with AspectJ, but eclipse compliator will always give you problem. its should be possible to ignore compiler errors.